# How do I remove an outline from Fireworks from text in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, adobe-fireworks

In Fireworks, I saved a file as a PSD so I could edit it in Photoshop. It included some text with a stroke. In Photoshop, the text appears with a stroke but I can't edit it or even find any indication it exists in any of the panels. Blending options shows no stroke. No other panel I've looked at shows it either.

**[Here's the PSD](https://img.collectorbookstore.com/stack/outline.psd)**

[image: Outlined text. But why is it outlined??]

Comment: Is it a pixel/raster layer in Ps?

Comment: No, a text layer. I can change the text, font, size, color, and everything, but not get rid of the path.

Comment: I don't know Fireworks. Does this layer has some connection/link with Fireworks or is it independent?

Comment: The stroke would probably be a layer style if it is a text layer. If not, can you select the text to see what the font is and re-write the word?

Comment: If you can change everything but can't seem to access the stroke --- why not just create a *new text layer* in Photoshop using the same font, size, color?

Comment: Check there isn't a layer style (stroke effect)) on the text layer itself, or even a layer style applied to a group in which the text layer is located.

Comment: There are no layer styles. I could just re-type it but I really want to know what's going on.

Comment: @richardthepratt can you add a screenshot of layer panel?

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: One more thing please. Are you able to change this text? I mean add more characters? Also, what font name is it showing in Character panel?

Comment: If you could, can you share the open file?

Comment: I've added the PSD

Comment: That is interesting... I can find no option to remove or alter that stroke. A *new layer* set in Impact at 100pt matches though. Seems like this is one for Adobe support. If you clear overrides for the Character Style [none] it resets and removes it.. but it also clears all other settings, i.e. font, size, color etc. Opening the PSD in **Illustrator** *does* show the stroke and *is* accessible as a vector object there.